# How do I see if a port is in use on a windows machine?

Tags: windows, port

I am using Windows XP pro, and I need to know if something is registered on a port.

If so how can I tell what is on the port?

**EDIT**

What I mean by registered is that I am trying to test a .NET remoting application, and I need to see if the application is running or registered on a given port.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`netstat -a -b` will show all listening ports and the executable name (rather than just the PID).

If you prefer a graphical version, [Microsoft's TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) will show you the same information, updating in real-time.

Comment: What about searching for particular port is in use or not

Comment: @Kilanny The `findstr` command finds lines that match some pattern, so pipe the `netstat` output into it: `netstat -a | findstr 8888`

Comment: @Kilanny Or, redirect the output to a file and search it with your text editor: `netstat -a -b > output.txt`

Answer (score 4):

[TCPview from the Sysinternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) does it in a nice, GUI way.

It includes a configurable update interval, address resolving and difference highlighting. And it is a lot faster than `netstat -a -b`.

Also available as a command line version (tcpvcon.exe). Both are free.

Comment: This tool just made my day. Once again sysinternals to the rescue. Never had a need for this before, it won't be forgotten!

Comment: So nice to see that an eight-year-old answer still helps people. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 3):

How do you define "registered"?

Anyway, netstat -o will list the currently used and listening ports with PIDs and tasklist (or whatever process id lister is available) would sort the process name and executable out I guess? ^^

edit: Oh nice, didn't notice the netstat -b option - that's obviously the better option :)

Answer (score 3):

Run **netstat** from the command line and it will show you all of the current connections.  **netstat -b** will show you what program is using the port.