# Tomcat won't start - how to check that port 8080 is not in use

Tags: windows, tomcat, startup

Tomcat won't start, and it has worked perfectly before. I suspect something else is running on port 8080. I am running Windows Vista. How do I check that nothing else is using port 8080?

I have recently downloaded several versions of Jetty. Could this be the problem? I am not running them concurrently so I can't see how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I see if a port is in use on a windows machine?](https://serverfault.com/questions/2699/how-do-i-see-if-a-port-is-in-use-on-a-windows-machine)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Open up a command prompt and run

`netstat -ano | findstr 8080`

Rightmost column is PID

In task manager you can add column for PID then find the app that is using the port.

Comment: use | findstr 8080 or | findstr LISTENING to filter the netstat output

Answer (score 1):

I think you can run cmd as administrator and use netstat command to see if port 8080 is being used. Use `netstat /?` for help with netstat command. I do not know any GUI based approach for the same.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to netstat you can also use [**Process Hacker**](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) or [**ActivePorts**](http://download.cnet.com/Active-Ports/3000-2651_4-29653.html?tag=mncol) to view open ports in real-time (ok, specific refresh intervals...)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily using the netstat utility.

Answer (score 0):

use NETSTAT in a command prompt.

Wikipedia also lists the [parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat).

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
netstat -aon | findstr "8080"
```

This command will give process ID's. Then go to task manager and stop the process with this process id and then restart tomcat.

Answer (score -1):

```
telnet localhost 8080
```

If you can connect, then something's listening on the port.

Comment: Tomcat could be listening just on internal / external interface and not on all / loopback interface. This test is not perfect.

Comment: also, a port is not necessarily available just because there is no application properly accepting connections.