# Tomcat service start issue

Tags: tomcat

I have installed tomcat as service successfully. when i start this from control Panel-> administrative tools -> services, it tows error like this,

> The Apache Tomcat 4.1 service on local computer started and then
>   stopped. Some service stop automatically if they have no work to do,
>   for example, the performance logs and alerts sevice.

Wat is the error?

Comment: Which version of windows is this?

Comment: Belongs on ServerFault or SuperUser -- I'm not sure.  It will be moved over shortly.  In the meantime, check the `logs` directory in your Tomcat installation for any errors.

Comment: Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]

Comment: The error message you're seeing is a generic Windows message.  You may find more details in the Tomcat logs.

Comment: I faced the same issue. In my case, I had not properly configured the Tomcat heap size. JvMs, JvMx

Answer (score 1):

If any server/service has issues, you should always be going straight to the logs.

```
$:\Tomcat4.1\logs\stdout.log
$:\Tomcat4.1\logs\stderr.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe port 80 or 8080 is used by another application

[Tomcat won't start - how to check that port 8080 is not in use](https://serverfault.com/questions/43617/tomcat-wont-start-how-to-check-that-port-8080-is-not-in-use)

Comment: I tried some other port like 8201. But it throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

CAn you check if you have the sufficient rights to start the service. otherwise use this to set a proper one.
 http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cmgmt/v8r3m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sysadmin.hlp/msr10034.htm

Comment: Yes. I loggined as administartor.

Comment: your apache log or windows service log will be of more help as ZoogieZork has commented above.